# find_in_set() not finding all values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hashtag

I have records in my database as:

```
hashtag -   description -   tags -  location -  time -  day

#social -  description - social media, facebook, social networking sites, social media, smartphone - usa - Tuesday

#php -  description - programming language, coding, open source - usa - Tuesday

#iphone -  description - smartphone, apple, iphone apps, costly phone, touch screen - usa - Tuesday
```

here tags are comma separated values.

Now if user searches `programming` - the result will be `2nd row`.

```
"coding"  - 2nd row
"smartphone" - 3rd & 1st row.
"iphone" - 3rd row
```

So, It is like search for tags or directly the hash keyword. First column is `hashkeyword`. tags are stored comma separated in the database.

I am using `find_in_set()` for this but it seems to be not working correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM `hash`WHERE `hashtag` LIKE 'smartphone' OR find_in_set('smartphone', tags)
```

Its returning only first row i.e.

```
iphone -    iphone description - smartphone, apple, apps, touchscreen - India   - tuesday
```

But "smartphone" value is also in 3rd row so it should have to return 1st and 3rd row.

Where I am going wrong? or is there any different method for searching like this instead of `find_in_set()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax of [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) is:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tablename`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( `column`, 'val1,val2' )
```

Edit:

You can use LIKE for text search:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tablename`
WHERE tags LIKE '%TAG%'
```

Comment: I tried this : `SELECT *
FROM  hash WHERE FIND_IN_SET( "tags", "smartphone" );` but its not returning anything

Comment: yes, its not like (like '%string%') or its not searches in the middle of the string

Comment: This answer is misleading. find_in_set usage in the example is correct. Spaces before and/or after commas causing the problem. You can remove spaces from your db or query like this (although not recommended): `FIND_IN_SET('smartphone', REPLACE(tags, ', ', ','))`

Comment: @J.K.A.
SELECT * FROM hash WHERE FIND_IN_SET( "smartphone" , tags);

This will work. For the column name, there is no need for "

Answer (score 1):

If you have space after the comma, then `FIND_IN_SET` won't work properly.

It will find in `smartphone, apple, apps, touchscreen` but it won't find in `apple, smartphone, apps, touchscreen`.

For an alternative solution, try the [***mysql full text search***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html).